# Override chef attributes globally from a cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, rbenv

We're using chef to manage Ruby versions in our vagrant setup using rbenv and ruby-build. One feature we'd like, even though rbenv pointedly refuses to implement it, is to have "fuzzy" version matching for ruby versions (e.g. converting 1.9.3 to 1.9.3-p123).

I'd like this to be handled transparently in a standalone recipe which can be placed between ruby-build and rbenv in the run_list. My code "works" (determines the latest matching ruby version based on the output of `ruby-build --definitions`), but changes are not persisted when running the rbenv cookbook, so I assume they are local to my cookbook. Is there any way to update an attribute globally for the duration of the run?

I should add that I'm not familiar with chef. This is outside of the domain that I usually work in. I know that this is probably a strange use case, and if what I'm trying to do is truly egregious, what would be a better way to accomplish what I want?

Here's the general outline of my current recipe:

```
original_rbenv_rubies = node[:rbenv][:rubies]
new_rbenv_rubies = determine_full_ruby_versions original_rbenv_rubies
node.force_override[:rbenv][:rubies] = new_rbenv_rubies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by using my cookbook as a wrapper for the rbenv cookbook. I moved the logic above into the default attributes file, and used `include_recipe` to include the original recipes in my own. For some reason, the new attributes still weren't being picked up, so I moved the original values into `node[:rbenv_wrapper][:rubies]`, and used `override` to set the new ones in `node[:rbenv][:rubies]`, after which everything worked as expected.